# Meaning(s) of 好 in 房子刚盖好，还没装窗户呢

Tags: grammar

> 房子刚盖好，还没装窗户呢
>
> Since the house was built just recently, windows have not been installed yet.

The translation above was done by me using free translation(namely not translating directly term by term).

What does this 好 mean in the sentence?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

剛蓋 does mean build/built, but it implies that something is jury rigged/barely standing etc.

In this case, with no other context: I would take it to mean "the house is barely built/standing". Perhaps there is still scaffolding and the walls are not completed (I won't lie, some of this mental image comes from pre-existing knowledge of when in the house building process windows are put in).

In this case 好 is a common verb compliment showing "finished".

So with 好 the phrase now becomes "the house is barely finished building/standing".  This continues to reinforce the fact that walls and a roof are just put up, while the actual interior of the house is probably not even started yet (this is that point in the home process when windows are usually added if wondering).

Comment: This is patently wrong IMHO. 剛蓋好 is short for 剛才建成不久, 剛剛修造完了, 'just finished building', the 好 being a resultative complement indicating completion ('finished'), 剛 indicating recency ('just'), and 蓋 a verb meaning 'construction (of a house)' (I'd suspect originally meaning 'roofing', 'putting the roof on top', thus 'build a house')

Comment: @JohnFrazer you describe the literal characters separately, not as a combined term, here is a dictionary definition supporting what I said: https://www.zdic.net/hant/搭蓋  of course, chinese vocab is always context based, if you have a source to show otherwise please feel free-- if unfamiliar with home constduction context-- the roof will go up before windows usually, but not always.  the walls both inside and outside will not be completed at all. this is still only for the purpose of avoiding side damage when roofing, some still do windows before roof expecially on bigger buildings.